# Create Pointcut for Spring AOP annotation to put annotation on class and execute advice on every method in class

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to have annotation **on class level** that will execute advice **on every method** in annotated class.
Is that even possible.

**Example:** I would like to annotate `OmniDemoService` with `@DoSomethingForMe` and I want both *method1* and `method2` to log "*look at me*" before execution

This example is not working and I don't know why. When I transform Pointcut to Around and just use it with annotation (also change annotation ElementType to method) everything is working on method level.
So I think it is wrong defined Pointcut.

Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DoSomethingForMe {
}
```

Advice:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DoSomethingForMeAdvice {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DoSomethingForMeAdvice.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(DoSomethingForMe)")
    public void anyAnnotatedMethod() {
    }

    @Before("anyAnnotatedMethod()")
    public void acquireExecution() {
        logger.info("look at me");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Service
@DoSomethingForMe
public class OmniDemoService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OmniDemoService.class);

    public void method1() {
            logger.info("---1---");
    }
    
    public void method2() {
            logger.info("---2---");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, that is possible, I don't really understand the actual question. What is the question you are having?

Comment: This is not working for me. Probably Pointcut is not defined well.

Comment: this might be a good read: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-annotation

Comment: This is just simple explanation of usage of advice on method level with @Around

Comment: Yes, I know. What is your point? have you tried copying that configuration, changing the target type and changing the location of the annotation?

Comment: Yes. As I said in question: "When I transform Pointcut to Around and just use it with annotation (also change annotation ElementType to method) everything is working on method level. So I think it is wrong defined Pointcut."
So I'm wondering is there something wrong with the Pointcut.
How would you define Pointcut for this situaction?

Comment: The problem with the 3 answers I have seen here is that each of them contains helpful information and none is wrong per se, but none is 100% correct or an ideal answer either. I do not want to write yet another one and steal someone's reputation. Maybe one of the authors wants to improve his answer to be complete and correct.

Comment: @kriegaex I would love to see a 100% answer and to learn something! :) Please do post your own answer, or give a suggestion how to improve the answer

Comment: @Hawk, you updated your answer already after my feedback - good job! :-) You could (a) incorporate the OP's `@within` solution (which actually is J Asgarov's solution) and (b) support your answer by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is what I usually do in my own answers. Of  course, the latter is optional, but because you asked about 100%. I repeat: Your answer per se is correct, just like the other one is. This thread is a bit messed up, the best answer having been provided in a comment re-posted as an answer by the OP, but in an incomplete way.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are confusing pointcut definition with advices.

Pointcut is aiming, advice performs the actual WhateverYouWantToBeExecuted. Like for example

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.omnidemo.advice.DoSomethingForMe)")
public void anyAnnotatedMethod() {
}


@Before("anyAnnotatedMethod()")
public void logMethodCall(JoinPoint jp) {
    String methodName = jp.getSignature().toShortString();
    logger.info("Executing: " + methodName);
}
```

Comment: You are right. That's because I used @Around which combines both.

However this still doesn't solve my problem 

If I do this




    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(LimitExecutionRate)")
    public void anyAnnotatedMethod() {
    }

    @Before("anyAnnotatedMethod()")
    public void acquireExecution() {
        logger.info("look at me");
        rateLimiter.acquire();
    }


      It won't work again

Comment: can you show updated code? and also the target class?

Comment: Oh I see already, because you have annotated the class (I thought directly the methods) you need to use within, like so: `@Pointcut("@within(com.omnidemo.advice.DoSomethingForMe)")`

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks :D 

It needed F-ing within

Answer (score 0):

Check out what the [AspectJ quick reference](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf) says about `@annotation()`:

> any join point where the subject has an annotation of type
> `SomeAnnotation`

You used `@annotation(DoSomethingForMe)` but the "[subject](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/join-point-modifiers.html#join-point-modifiers)" of a method execution is a **method**. So that would mean *any* method annotated @DoSomethingForMe.

Use `@this(DoSomethingForMe)` or `@target(DoSomethingForMe)`.

Thanks to [kriegaex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082681/kriegaex) for pointing out that `@this` and `@target` must be evaluated at runtime, which would pollute the codebase a lot (i.e. check in every method). So the next approach is better:

---

If you check the AspectJ manual section about [type patterns](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html#type-patterns) you will see that you can annotate the type directly. Please also remember to use use fully qualified class names. So that would be:

```java
execution(public * (@com.path.DoSomethingForMe *).*(..))
```

Also, if you have such a simple pointcut and you don't need to reuse it, I think you can drop the additional method and just use it in the advice directly:

```java
@Before("execution(public * (@com.path.DoSomethingForMe *).*(..))")
```

which says: "before the execution of any public method of a type annotated with `@com.path.DoSomethingForMe`", where "before the execution of a method" means "inside the method, at the beginning".

---

Alternatively, if this pointcut looks a bit too complicated for you, you can separate annotation matching and method matching like this, as suggested by [J Asgarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12038714/j-asgarov) in his comment:

```java
@Before("execution(public * *(..)) && @within(com.path.DoSomethingForMe)")
```

Comment: I have decided to make your answer a bit more readable, fix and beautify some links and also incorporate the `@within` suggestion. I think now the answer contains all relevant information and some alternative solutions to choose from and should be accepted by the OP. I hope you don't mind me messing with your answer. Feel free to revert if for whatever reason you don't like it. But I really don't want the credit for an own answer because all the relevant information was already given by you and J Asgarov.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the problem is to use within for pointcut

```
@Pointcut("@within(DoSomethingForMe)")
public void anyAnnotatedMethod() {
}

@Before("anyAnnotatedMethod()")
public void acquireExecution() {
    logger.info("look at me");
}
```

Solution provided by @J Asgarov in the comments

Comment: that would catch non-public methods too

Comment: and constructors, and static initializers and... **ANY** code.

Comment: @Hawk, I think it it trivial to combine `@within` with `&& execution(public * *(..))`. The OP  uses it in his question already, the only thing he got wrong was using `@annotation` instead of `@within`. What is better in your answer is that you use a fully qualified class name for the annotation, which is necessary unless by chance or by design the annotation happens to be in the same package as the aspect. The problem with `@this` and `@target` is that while they work, they are evaluated during runtime and are thus potentially slower than `@within` which is determined during compile time.

Comment: well it's not _trivial_ because in the given code (anyAnnotatedMethod) there explicitly is no mention of an execution joinpoint. If it were, then okay. (Even though I think there could potentially be the field set/get joinpoint caught inside the method.)
 The runtime evaluation is a good point! But I also added another option defining the annotated type, which should be compile-time.

Comment: I said that the OP's **question** already uses `execution(..) && ...`, I was not talking about this **answer**. So I figure that the OP already knows how to combine pointcuts, which would make it trivial for him to add it.